# How to handle a great number of different Button commands?

Tags: java, command, action, undo, command-pattern

I want to resolve a variation of different Button events **in Java**:

I have a dozen of different buttons which will do **different actions**.
All together it's like I have about 40 to 50 Buttons or 40 to 50 different possible commands.

Then I have lots of parameters, called a..z and A..Z.
Every Button-Event will lead to the incrementation of some of the parameters, for example:
`button#1`  will **increase a,b,c and u**.
`Button#2`  will **increase f and y**.
`Button#5`  will **increase AFG and el**.

You can see, it's getting very complex, but still ok, if I would not need to implement an undo-option.

Thus, I need to

1. Somehow tell my model to increase a bunch of parameters NOT by calling `.increaseA(); .increase_x(); .increaseWhatever();` for every possible parameter.
2. Remember and invert the processed commands, with respect to the increased parameters (which can vary at type and amount)

Normally, the **Command-Pattern** would be my choice for Undo-Options, but here I would get over 50 different classes, because every command would increase different parameters, even if the actual operation is the same: **increasing parameters**.

I would be grateful, if somebody could show me a very clean solution to this.

---

My approach so far would be to mix the Command pattern with some kind of String-parser:
Using a hashmap, containing the button-id as key, and the String consisting of the parameters to be increased, as value.  For example: `<button1, "abcefgWY+1">`
Then I would only need my Model with the String parser, which would resolve the command... but that does not solve the UNDO problem, and I am asking if this is a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

What about having a hashmap of Integers with the associated letter as key and the value is the actual value like this `myIntegers<Character, IntegerValue>`.

Your `<button1, "abcedgWY">` might be something more like `<buttonX, buttonObject>` where button object is a Character array and a counter for how many times increment has happened so that you know how many decrements are allowed.  Step through your Character array using each character as the key for the myIntegers hashmap and increment or decrement per the button or the undo option.

If it's just a general undo you will need a stack to push and pop, which can be a stack of buttonid's.  If its an undo button for each increment button you just have to track how many undo's each increment is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. When I would press Button1 increasing e.g. the characters abc, and then press button2 increasing afg, then button3 with bhj...  wouldn't an undo from button3 not also decrement characters from button2 (too early)? (Because you said I can see if undo is possible depending on the counter).

I like the Idea with the Hashmap and using the Stack for undo (which I already considered using) though :)

I should have mentioned, that it is not possible to press the same button multiple times in a row.

Comment: if you drive the undo calls only through popping the stack you don't have to worry about order at all.  

I was more concerned with how your undo option is presented to the user.  In your last comment pressing 1, 2, 3 and the undoing 3 would be fine.  But, if you present undo buttons that are enabled without first checking the buttonObject to see if it has been incremented then you would have the decrement issue.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for the facade-design pattern...

there you can create your custom sub-commands...

but when it comes to coding, you may be helped with a simpler solution, as desired you call facade-methode:

```
private void increaseAllOf(String whichOne, int amount) {

    for (char c: whichOne.toCharArray() ){
        switch(c){
        case 'a' : {increaseWhereElse(amount);break;}
        case 'b' : {increaseOnOtherPlace(amount);break;}

        }
    }

}
```

you can define in the switch-statement which method will be called, depending on the characters of the `whichOne`-String

Comment: I would upvote if I could (not enough reputation)!
Thanks! It's not the overall solution but helps a lot for sure :)

Comment: thanks, if i can provide further ideas let me know =)